# IBM Worklight - iOS 7 status bar overlaps app's HTML

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

In my application, the top of the HTML is half way into status bar. I have a button in that section that is now impossible to click.

I don't know why it would do this. I have the standard viewport line ("width=device-width").
  Any ideas? Or how to adjust it?

Comment: Setting the "marginTop" worked PERFECTLY for the opening screen (looks awesome)...but as soon as I switch pages (.changePage()) it is back to overlapping. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That other page you are loading likely loads a different div and if that div does not receive the same styling as the original div, the problem will re-appear.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the steps given by Idan above, you can try using one preference in iOS which hides the statusbar.

Try adding the following method to your app's root view controller:

> - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
>     return YES; }

Or you can add 20px space on the top after determining the iOS version

> function onDeviceReady() {
>
> ```
> if (parseFloat(window.device.version) === 7.0) {
>        document.body.style.marginTop = "20px";
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

Comment: I would not recommend that unless what you are looking for is HIDING the status bar; in most apps the status bar is still desirable, so need to make sure the correct version is used.

Comment: Hi Idan, 

This was not my question, I proposed one alternate we used here, the question belongs to Stakutis. I don't know which approach he ended up with :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are following the guidelines provided by IBM in regards to iOS 7 support, as well as using the latest version of Worklight containing this support.

You can read more about it, here:

- [IBM Worklight Versions 6.0.0 and 5.0.6 Support Apple iOS 7](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574)

---

I also see that you mention using jQuery Mobile...
Perhaps, then, you should take a look at the [Worklight Starter jQuery Mobile edition](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/WorklightStarter_jQueryMobile.zip) that looks OK in 7.x; take a look at the CSS.

W/out a demo app from you to understand how exactly you've styled your app, a fuller answer cannot be given.

A comment by you:

> Setting the "marginTop" worked PERFECTLY for the opening screen (looks
>   awesome)...but as soon as I switch pages (.changePage()) it is back to
>   overlapping. What am I doing wrong?

My guess is that the other page you are loading likely loads a different div and if that div does not receive the same styling as the original div, the problem will re-appear.