# IBM Worklight 6.1 - iOS 7 status bar overlays elements in HTML

Tags: ios7, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am building an app using IBM Worklight 6.1 for iOS 7. In iOS 7 the status bar is overlay my Webview and i followed the below link and fix for the same issue.

But, it changes the style as iOS 6 and provided a scroll in my webview for that 20 pixel, so my page can be scroll up and hide the header for 20 pixel.

Please let me know if someone has a solution...

Screenshot 1:
[image]

Screenshot 2:
[image]

Comment: What is the question? What do you want to change? Add a screenshot (upload it to imgur and provide a link) of how it is  now, and explain how you'd like it to be

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to upload image. Please refer the link i have posted.

Comment: Hi Please refer your post in this thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011040/ibm-worklight-ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-apps-html

Comment: Hi, no. Since you are using Worklight 6.1 and the other question is 5 months old, I want you to better explain yours. Edit the question, add links to the images, explain what you want.

Comment: Hi Adar, Edited my post and updated the screenshots.

Comment: Updated the post with screen shots based on email I received from the poster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshots, it looks like the [HelloWorklight project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/HelloWorklightProject.zip) is being used.

In the context of this application, you can add the following to the `#header` in `common\css\main.css`:

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
```

This way, when swiping Up the status bar will not cover the header...
You can take a similar approach in your own app.

[Fixed positioning in CSS](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=css+fixed+positioning).

---

Note that in `iphone\css\main.css` you can alter the styling of the default white status bar that is "injected" by the Worklight framework.